# MVC ASP Como insertar en dos tablas

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Hola soy un novato en el tema , quería pedirles ayuda con un problema.

Requiero insertar datos de dos clases en una sola vista, donde el usuario pueda insertar **N registros** en la segunda tabla .

He generado una vista parcial de la segunda clase pero da error en el modelo.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public string NombreCompleto { get; set; }

    public int BeneficiarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Beneficiario Beneficiario { get; set; }
}


public class Beneficiario
{
    public int BeneficiarioId { get; set; }

    public string Nombre  { get; set; }

    public string Parentesco { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que intento realizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el código que tienes y que error te marca?

Comment: Indica por favor el texto completo del error que te da.

Comment: Me quedan dos vistas aparte de create no comprendo como unirlas

Comment: Una pregunta: en tu estructura, son muchos beneficiarios para un cliente, o al revés, muchos clientes para un solo beneficiario?

Comment: Muchos beneficiarios para un cliente